# Serve Static files without html extension in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I want deploy the Help documentation in Google App Engine.
The site has been generated through Blacksmith which generate links without .html extension.
These links does not work with existing App Engine Setup.

Is there any configuration to serve static file without .html extension?

Answer (score 0):

In what way do they not work with appengine ?  You can't access the file, a browser doesn't render it, just tries to download ?  You will need to be a lot more specific.

Static files don't need any specific extension, though some browsers might, and the content type will need to be defined for a resource without an extension.

from the docs for static resources.

Changing the MIME Type for Static Files

By default, static files are served using a MIME type selected based on the filename extension. You can associate custom MIME types with filename extensions for static files in web.xml using elements.

Comment: Thanks Tim for the reply.
Browser says, **Error: NOT_FOUND.**. It is 404 Error.
I have file like '/Prospects/Create_Prospect.html'. But i had link like **/Prospects/Create_Prospect**.

Comment: Well that means you haven't configured you static handlers correctly. Either the static file has not been uploaded or the static handler hasn't been defined to server the static file.

Comment: The static handler is working for some links. The link **/Getting_Started/** does bring the index.html under **Getting_Started** folder. But the link **/Getting_Started/index** does not work(404 error). I expect it should return **/Getting_Started/index.html** page

Comment: I doubt names have anything to do with it.  See the docs.  You are using static handler aren't you.  Include you definition of your static handler.

Comment: I set my public root and Everything works if i provide .html extension to the page.  My appeninge-web.xml -  http://pastebin.com/SL45GvQF

What you mean by static handlers?

Comment: ok, rereading your earlier comment if you links don't match the files then you have a problem ;-)   Does  /Getting_Started/index.html actually work.  You could just rename all you files to match the links. (ie drop the extension)

Comment: Unfortunately the HTML files are generated from Markdown file by Blacksmith tool. So i could not change them manually. Is there any other way to serve html file even if i request without .html extension?

Comment: Do the the links inside the html file include the extension ?  If they don't then there really isn't any reason to not rename them.

Comment: The links does not have .html extension. The blacksmith does not add .html extension to the link. Even if i add them manually, it will be overwritten, it will be overwritten in next build.